How to utilize product graphs in graph signal processing?
I'm working with dynamic graph signal processing. How to plot time variation and spatial variation separately and take the cartesian product of those two graphs?

It seems to me this is what you are looking for: Roddenberry et al Signal Processing On Product Spaces (2023)

PSH : It would greatly assist if readers had a chance to read some of your code regarding this question, if possible indeed
